# Why i can't find transfered in storm ui?

Tags: apache-storm

i'm new to storm i submitted `storm-starter` and what i got is 
[image]

i think everythin is ok as i thought but why `acker_1 emitted 0`

and after that i submitted my imported project got that 
[image]

i tried to kill it and resubmit it again after closing `nimbus,supervisor,drpc,ui and zookeeper` connection and got that 
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Are there any errors in the log files?

Comment: i have still hasn't  start  in supervisor when checked i got in the worker [ERROR] Async loop died!
org.zeromq.ZMQException: Address already in use(0x62)
 at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.bind(Native Method)
 at zilch.mq$bind.invoke(mq.clj:69)
 at backtype.storm.messaging.zmq.ZMQContext.bind(zmq.clj:57)
 at backtype.storm.messaging.loader$launch_receive_thread_BANG_$fn__1629.invoke(loader.clj:26)
 at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
 at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2015-12-16 02:25:36 util [INFO] Halting process:

Comment: but how can i got this in port and storm-starter worked well ?

Comment: It seems you are using a quite old version of Storm? ZMQ got replaced by Netty in newer versions. Can you upgrade to a newer Storm version?

Comment: i upgraded it before but problem still with cannot bind port

Answer (score 0):

check your _acker bolt, whether it EMITs something or not. Try to find something in storm logs (logs in storm_directory/logs/worker-logport.log)

Comment: Thanks i checked it with debugging and found that supervisor still hasn't start and got too this statement Could not extract resources from /home/user/storms/storm/supervisor/tmp/f5e8e47a-9e6d-48c4-a27c-ef39e08704c6/stormjar.jar

Comment: i think you configured your storm.yaml file not properly

Comment: my storm.yaml is storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "myipaddress"
nimbus.host: "myipaddress"
storm.local.dir: /home/user/storms/storm
supervisor.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
nimbus.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
worker.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6704
    - 6705
    - 6706
    - 6707
topology.debug: true
 is there anything wrong ?

Comment: as i know, you should also configure storm directory and other properties

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/
this tutorial was helpful for me

Comment: thanks i will check it again but do you know what is the exactly should i add because i submitted another project with the same setting without any problem so what should be wrong ?

Comment: if so, you have a bug in your topology))

Comment: i thought that but it's a project i imported it from github could it may be awrong ?

Comment: send me link to github

Comment: did you get the link ?

Comment: yes, but, there is no such topology, i think you talk about word-counter topology?

Comment: the topology is in line 81 startec with public static StormTopology buildTopology(LocalDRPC drpc) {
  TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology(); and fsd the name of the topology

Comment: seems to be alright, why you use someone's topology? why not your own?

Comment: actually, do not know, but i think bug is in your updated code(

Comment: can i contact you in your email ?